# az webapp create errow when specifying .net core

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

If I run the following commands:

`az appservice plan create --name PluralsightTestPlan --resource-group PluralsightTest --sku FREE
az webapp create -g PluralsightTest -p PluralsightTestPlan -n PluralsightTestapp --runtime "DOTNETCORE|2.1"`

Then i get the following error:
`Runtime 'DOTNETCORE|2.1' is not supported. Please invoke 'list-runtimes' to cross check`

The same error occurs no matter what version of .net core i use.

When i run:

`az webapp list-runtimes`

Then no .net core runtimes are specified unless i use the --linux switch.

If i use a .net framework value then it works.

Comment: Looks like a known issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/7688

Comment: In fact, both Windows and Linux should support .netcore 2.1, which may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks all. Have posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KNown issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/7688

Thanks to Amit Baranes for the answer.

Comment: This is really a issue. Can you mark yourself answer as the answer of this question? This will help others.:)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you face now:

[image]

The `az webapp list-runtimes` tells us it doesn't support .netcore 2.1. And if run `az webapp list-runtimes --linux`, it says when on linux, it will be supported.

But I created a web app based on linux service plan P1v2 and still get this error. As it describes, this error should not happen when based on linux. In fact, I can successfully create the same configuration on Portal. In fact, both Windows and Linux should support .netcore 2.1 This may be a bug.

If you don't have special needs, you can temporarily create a web app using Portal.